# MAMP Pro successfully loading services and servers, but it doesn't work

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I used Mamp Pro for several years and everything used to run smoothly. However, I'm no longer able to let it work: when I start, I can see Apache and MySql starting correctly, however I can't load any host. If I try to open http://localhost:8888/any_site or https://sslhost:8890/any_site it would try forever to load the page, without success.
The latest lines of my apache_error.log are:

```
mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_perl/2.0.10 
Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 13 19:59:16 2020] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 13 20:05:18 2020] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 13 20:05:18 2020] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jan 13 20:05:18 2020] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1308)
[Mon Jan 13 20:05:18 2020] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_perl/2.0.10 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

My mysql_error.log says:

```
    2020-01-13T19:34:24.275941Z 435 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-01-13T19:34:24.293412Z 436 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304394Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304431Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304438Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304502Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304894Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304914Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304947Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304960Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.304971Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305007Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305071Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305079Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305087Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305114Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305120Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305127Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305136Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305143Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305151Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305157Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305164Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305171Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305177Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305183Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305190Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305196Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305209Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305220Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305231Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305241Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305251Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305263Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305272Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305279Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305286Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305292Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305299Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305306Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305318Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305327Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305337Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305415Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-01-13T19:34:24.305518Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-01-13T19:34:24.405790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-13T19:34:24.406211Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200113 20:34:24
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928194Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1807178926
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928781Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928807Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928818Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928827Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928835Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.928943Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-01-13T19:34:24.929409Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-01-13T19:34:24.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
2020-01-13T19:34:26.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2020-01-13T19:34:27.175777Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.176074Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26) starting as process 60146 ...
2020-01-13T19:34:27.180615Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2020-01-13T19:34:27.183286Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-01-13T19:34:27.183334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-13T19:34:27.183353Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-01-13T19:34:27.183372Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-13T19:34:27.183418Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2020-01-13T19:34:27.185854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-13T19:34:27.186027Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-01-13T19:34:27.187854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-01-13T19:34:27.198530Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-13T19:34:27.212129Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.246293Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-13T19:34:27.246434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-13T19:34:27.252212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.253237Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.253260Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.253385Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-13T19:34:27.303666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.26 started; log sequence number 1807178926
2020-01-13T19:34:27.303842Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-13T19:34:27.303894Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.307659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200113 20:34:27
2020-01-13T19:34:27.308458Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-01-13T19:34:27.308992Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-01-13T19:34:27.314420Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2020-01-13T19:34:27.323080Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-01-13T19:34:27.323197Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.26'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-01-13T19:34:27.657126Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-01-13T19:34:27.668078Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-01-13T19:34:27.678890Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-01-13T19:34:27.700996Z 6 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Could any of you understand what is going on?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution to my problem after many days... My MAMP PRO activities were blocked by the firewall of Nod32.

Please consider the opportunity of disabling that firewall if you think that might cause the same issue.